# Proper way how to prepare data in async cancellable workflow with responsive UI

Tags: user-interface, asynchronous, f#, mailboxprocessor

This question is based on [Async.TryCancelled doesn't work with Async.RunSynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601299/async-trycancelled-doesnt-work-with-async-runsynchronously) that looks complex, so I will cut a simple part that I try to solve.

Suppose I have this functions:

```
let prepareModel () = 
    async {
        // this might take a lot of time (1-50seconds)
        let! a = ...
        let! b = ...
        let! res = combine a b
        return res
    }
 let updateUI model =
    runOnUIThread model
```

`prepareModel` prepares data that should be displayed to the user. `updateUI` refreshes the UI (removes old controls and creates new ctls based on new data).

**Question:** How should I call the two functions so that `prepareModel` is cancellable any time?

The flow is

- user clicks refresh

  - `prepareModel`(1) started and is running asynchronously, so the UI is responsive and user can work with the application
- user changes data and clicks refresh again

  - `prepareModel`(1) from is cancelled and 
    new `prepareModel`(2) is started
- user changes data and clicks refresh again

  - `prepareModel`(2) is cancelled and 
    new `prepareModel`(3) is started
  - ..
  - `prepareModel`(n) finished
  - `updateUI` is ran on UI thread, redraws the UI

*(My first solution is based on `MailboxProcessor` that ensures that only one `prepareModel` is executed, see at [Async.TryCancelled doesn't work with Async.RunSynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601299/async-trycancelled-doesnt-work-with-async-runsynchronously) but as I experimented with this, it's not bug free)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach would be to start the workflow asynchronously in the background using `Async.Start` (then it should be cancellable). To redraw the UI at the end, you can use `Async.SwitchToContext` to make sure that the last part of the workflow executes on the UI. Here is a sketch:

```
// Capture current synchronization context of the UI
// (this should run on the UI thread, i.e. when starting)
let syncContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current

// Cancellation token source that is used for cancelling the
// currently running workflow (this can be mutable)
let cts = ref (new CancellationTokenSource())

// Workflow that does some calculations and then updates gui
let updateModel () =   
    async {  
        // this might take a lot of time (1-50seconds)  
        let! a = ...  
        let! b = ...  
        let! res = combine a b 

        // switch to the GUI thread and update UI
        do! Async.SwitchToContext(syncContext)
        updateUserInterface res
    }  

// This would be called in the click handler - cancel the previous
// computation, creat new cancellation token & start the new one
cts.Cancel()
cts := new CancellationTokenSource()
Async.Start(updateModel(), cts.Token)
```